# ASP.net - The name 'pageNumber' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm trying to create a pager in ASP.net and am running into an error.

Trying to do this in my markup:

```
<div class="pager">
<% foreach(int pageNumber in this.PageCollection) { %>
    <% if( pageNumber == this.PageIndex ) { %>
        <span class="current"><%= pageNumber %></span>
    <% } else { %>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkGoToPage" runat="server" OnClick="lnkGoToPage_Click"><%= pageNumber %></asp:LinkButton>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'pageNumber' does not exist in the current context
```

The error is happening on the LinkButton line. It works fine on the first if case...but for some reason my variable does not exist on the else case.

Does anyone have any idea why this is not compiling or how I could do the same thing differently.

It's been a while since I have done regular ASP.net and I am used to the MVC way.

Comment: You could eliminate a lot of the embedded server markup

Comment: Might want to explain how instead of just saying it can be done. I asked for a better way to do it :)

Comment: I was just commented on the markup, not answering the question, hence the comment instead of answer!

Comment: ... And I'm asking you how you would eliminate some of the markup?

Comment: It's not the you should eliminate the markup as such, you just should not have all that server code mixed in with the markup.

Comment: @Dismissile Glad you figured out! Still, you can check my example below (edited one) as it is just one line change/addition to your original code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't place `<%= pageNumber %>` inside a LinkButton.

Alternatively, use the `Repeater` control and the `OnItemDataBound` event to add logic such as `pageNumber == this.PageIndex` in the code behind.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Pager" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="ltlGoToPage" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Literal>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkGoToPage" runat="server" OnClick="lnkGoToPage_Click" Visible="false"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

You can toggle the visibilty of the controls in the `OnItemDataBound` event.

In the code behind, reference the controls and apply any logic:

```
var ltlGoToPage = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltlGoToPage");
var lnkGoToPage = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("lnkGoToPage");
```

Comment: Used a repeater and it worked great. Not as clean/simple as I am used to with MVC but still works.

Comment: You nailed it, inline code in much more efficient in MVC, web form is... web form.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="pager">
<% foreach(int pageNumber in this.PageCollection) {
    if( pageNumber == this.PageIndex ) { %>
        <span class="current"><%= pageNumber.ToString() %></span>
    <% } else { %>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkGoToPage" runat="server" OnClick="lnkGoToPage_Click"><%= pageNumber.ToString() %></asp:LinkButton>
    <% }
} %>
```

This will help eliminate some of the markup. Also, called `ToString()` on page number as that's just common practice for me, but you might not want it that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you do things in asp.net web forms, you should do the loop in the code behind.

The error is caused by the fact that the problem `<%= pageNumber %>` is in the middle of a control.

Comment: How exactly would you loop in the code behind? I need to dynamically create the markup. I'm more of an MVC guy...

Comment: You don't dynamically create markup.  You can dynamically add controls to a page in code.  Usually you will put a panel or a placeholder control in the markup where you want the controls to go then add controls to the panel's controls collection in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about my previos post. I wanted to say the way I see it is to use Text property of the control.
This should work:

```
<div class="pager">
<% foreach(int pageNumber in this.PageCollection) { %>
    <% if( pageNumber == this.PageIndex ) { %>
        <span class="current"><%= pageNumber %></span>
    <% } else { %>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkGoToPage" runat="server" OnClick="lnkGoToPage_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
    <%
lnkGoToPage.Text = pageNumber.ToString();
} %>
<% } %>
```

Also, you should think about giving sdifferent IDs to the LinkButtons to make sure they are different. But, conceptually, the code above should work

Comment: Your code throws an exception: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs...